# Rejected-Recruiter provided feedbacks from HM but asked to keep in touch

Tags: hiring-process, recruitment, hiring, rejection

I was fortunate enough, as a fresh graduate, to get to the third of the four step of the recruitment process with a startup that has recently secured a 10million USD series B funding but unfortunate enough to pass through the third part of the recruitment process.

The hiring manager whom I was interviewing with yesterday has recently set up a data team where it is only a year or two later that a data scientist may be brought in once the data ecosystem has been "up and going". 
During the interview, I was constantly asked if a less technically equivalent role to my skillset would be "OK" and if I would be "bored".

Long story short, the rejection email came in today from the in-house recruiter coupled with positive feedbacks while also addressing the obvious part. She has always been very personal.

> *Let's keep in touch and I wish you the best of luck in your job search, hope this feedback has helped you in someway or another.*

Should I interpret this as something more personal and genuine or a standardised ritual?

Comment: It seems like a pretty standard rejection letter. Although whether it's standard or personal shouldn't necessarily change whether and how you try to keep in touch.

Comment: @Dukeling Thank you. I have return a reply out of courtesy and drop my LinkedIn to which she connected with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard boiler-plate rejection, but the wording does leave some room for a positive interpretation.

Send a "hello" email every so often to this person.  If you get any sort of indication that this person is indeed wanting to keep in touch and this is not just a polite rejection, by all means, stay in touch.

If there is another opening in the future, they'll remember you, if not you might have a new friend.  **NEVER MISS AN OPPORTUNITY TO NETWORK**

Comment: @Physkid GRATZ!  great move!  good luck in the future!